# PHP: подскажите, пожалуйста, как применить класс Exception? В документации не могу понять

Tags: php, ооп, исключения, try-catch, try

Начинаю изучение класса Exception, прошу прощения, если вопрос кому-то покажется глупым. Хочу использовать наследование исключений в своем MVC предложении. Создал класс ErrorController, который наследует от встроенного класса Exception. Делаю в нем метод processServError(), чтобы использовать его в других классах для обработки нужной ошибки...

```
<?php

namespace Controller;

use Throwable;
use View\View;

use \Exception;

class ErrorController extends Exception
{
    private static $curlErr;

    function __construct($message = "", $code = 0, Throwable $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    public static function processServError($curlErr) {
        return self::$curlErr;
    }
```

Но когда в другом файле я пытаюсь сослаться на созданный метод таким образом:

```
if (!empty($curlErr)) {
            throw new ErrorController::processServError($curlErr);
        } else {
```

То выкинуть исключение с помощью throw не получается.. Хотя другие статические методы из других статических классов работают нормально...

Как же мне тогда использовать методы с различными ошибками из ErrorController? Подскажите, пожалуйста...

Comment: в PHP слово `new`  пишется в каком случае? Применимо к чему?

Comment: И второе - зачем наследовать __контроллер__ от __эксепшена__? Что в них общего?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский при создании экземпляра класса.. А в вызове статической функции не нужно его создавать. НО если бы я выбрасывал исключение без всякого класса, я бы написал так: throw new Exception('введены неверные данные!');

Comment: А Exception по-твоему что? не класс?))  А как же ты от него наследуешься? %))

Comment: @u_mulder мне показалось это логичным. ErrorController (я пишу авторизацию) у меня отвечает за открытие через View html-файлов в ответ на ошибки, допустим, неверный логин или пароль.. Я мог бы создать отдельный класс для Exceptionов, которые в моем приложении тоже используются только для обработки ошибок. Но зачем мне два класса для все этого, если оно служит одному и может быть объединено в одном классе?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский таким образом: ErrorController extends Exception {}

Comment: Следуя такой логике вообще всё можно объединить в один класс, всё же служит цели работы твоего приложения, так создай класс MyApplication и готово

Comment: "таким образом: ErrorController extends Exception" --- ты же написал, что "если бы я выбрасывал исключение без всякого класса, я бы написал так: throw new Exception" --- то есть `Exception` по-твоему высказыванию **не класс** ..... поэтому и резонный вопрос, а как ты смог отнаследоваться от не класса?)) и почему перед ним там new стоИт?))

Comment: @u_mulder вот я программист, поддерживающий этот код, захожу в проект, вижу два класса: ErrorController и MyApplication. Что такое MyApplication с первого взгляда не понимаю совсем, ErrorController похож на класс обработки ошибок, лезу туда, а там не все ошибки.... (Если myApplication я назову как-нибудь HTTPError, то все равно получается усложнение ненужное, зачем оно?) Если все сведено в ErrorController, то секунду посмотрел на код, за секунду понял, где искать все ошибки... Объединять все в одном файле я бы не стал, это перебор, но и делил бы только если прагматично...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, конечно, Exception это класс, проверил, без new, метод работает... в соответствии с синтаксисом вызова статических функций в другом классе... Но что-то мне подсказывает, что у меня получилось неправильное использование наследования Exception, а как правильно созданный потомок от Exception использовать в коде?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Прочитал, что try catch можно потом удобно использовать с этим классом, но объяснения мне непонятны...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> То выкинуть исключение с помощью throw не получается.. Хотя другие статические методы из других статических классов работают нормально...

Непонятна исходная постановка задачи и примеров вызова "других статических методов". Ваши ошибки в том, что

1. `Exception` - класс **исключения**. Расширять его следует только если пишете собственное **исключение**. Следовательно, `ErrorController` является **исключением**. Значит, выбрасывать его надо через `throw new ErrorController()`.

Закладывать в название и тело класса исключения алгоритмы и термины, которые не относится к **этому** исключению -- неправильно и вносит путаницу (хотя и не является ошибкой с на уровне языка). Это применимо к любому классу. Исключение не должно управлять исключениями.

2. Вы передаёте в `processServError()` какое-то значение, никак не используете внутри и возвращаете `self::$curlErr`, который вообще не инициализирован;
3. Судя по всему, вы пытаетесь создать динамическое определение имени исключения, которое следует выбрасывать, но в `new` не передаёте ни имя класса, ни переменную, его содержащую.

Могу предположить, что вам нужно, например, [такое](https://3v4l.org/CnoKD):

```php
<?php
// https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1444784

class MyExc1 extends \Exception {}
class MyExc2 extends \Exception {}
class ExcController
{
    private static $map = [
        22 => MyExc1::class,
        28 => MyExc2::class,
    ];

    public static function getExceptionClassByCode($curlErr) {
        return self::$map[$curlErr];
    }

    public static function throwExceptionByCode($curlErr, $msg) {
        throw new self::$map[$curlErr]($msg);
    }
}

//      обратите внимание на круглые скобки
/* 1 */ throw new (ExcController::getExceptionClassByCode(22)); // throw new (MyExc1);
/* 2 */ throw new (ExcController::getExceptionClassByCode(22))('qwerty'); // throw new (MyExc1)('qwerty')
/* 3 */ ExcController::throwExceptionByCode(22, 'qwerty'); // идентичный результат
```

Разница в том, что в первых двух примерах мы сначала получаем имя исключения **из метода** и выбрасываем его. В третьем примере мы выбрасываем исключение, взяв его имя **из переменной**.